# StructureMap problems with bidirectional/circular dependencies

Tags: structuremap, circular-dependency, bidirectional

I am currently integrating *StructureMap* within our business layer but have problems because of bidirectional dependencies.

The layer contains multiple managers where each manager can call methods on each other: there are no restrictions or rules for communication. This also includes possible circular dependencies like in the example below.
I know the design itself is questionable but currently we just want *StructureMap* to work and will focus on further refactoring in the future.

Every manager implements the `IManager` interface:

```
internal interface IManager
{
  bool IsStarted { get; }

  void Start();
  void Stop();
}
```

And also has its own specific interface:

```
internal interface IManagerA : IManager
{
  void ALogic();
}

internal interface IManagerB : IManager
{
  void BLogic();
}
```

Here are two dummy manager implementations:

```
internal class ManagerA : IManagerA
{
  public IManagerB ManagerB { get; set; }

  public void ALogic() { }

  public bool IsStarted { get; private set; }
  public void Start() { }
  public void Stop() { }
}

internal class ManagerB : IManagerB
{
  public IManagerA ManagerA { get; set; }

  public void BLogic() { }

  public bool IsStarted { get; private set; }
  public void Start() { }
  public void Stop() { }
}
```

Here is the *StructureMap* configuration I use at the moment.

I am still not sure how should I register the managers so currently I am using manual registration. Maybe someone could help me with this too.

```
For<IManagerA>().Singleton().Use<ManagerA>();
For<IManagerB>().Singleton().Use<ManagerB>();

SetAllProperties(convention =>
{
  // configure the property injection for all managers
  convention.Matching(prop => typeof(IManager).IsAssignableFrom(prop.PropertyType));
});
```

After all I cannot create `IManagerA` because *StructureMap* complains about the circular dependency between `ManagerA` and `ManagerB`. Is there an easy and clean solution to solve this problem but to keep the current design?

Answer (score 9):

> Patient: "Doc, it hurts when I poke my
>   finger in my eye"
>
> Doctor: "Stop poking your finger in
>   your eye."

No, there will be no "easy", nor "clean" solution that keeps the current design. When intuition, and your tools, tell you a design isn't working, its probably a good idea to listen.

If something needs an `IManagerA`, and an `IManagerB`, then it should take them both as dependencies. A dependency injection tool, like StructureMap, makes these types of composition scenarios easy - don't fight it.